# The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "beans" is not bound

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

Why am I having this error

> [Fatal Error]: The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "beans" is not bound.

at the header of my XML file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

The error is at the last line of my XML declaration. 
Please what can I do to remove this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

to your `bean` element to eliminate that error.

Comment: Works for me as well!